# Update table date field from other table when not null

Tags: sql-scripts

I want to update a Date filed for Entry type = 4 )in the table from some records (entry type = 1) in the same table however getting a cannot insert null data into the field error.

```
UPDATE [Item Ledger Entry] 
  SET [Last Invoice Date] = (Select  MAX([Posting Date])
                               from  [Item Ledger Entry] ILE2 
                               where ILE2.[Item No_] = ILE1.[Item No_] AND
                                     ILE2.[Posting Date] <= ILE1.[Posting Date] AND
                                     ILE2.[Entry Type] = 1 AND 
                                     ILE2.[Posting Date] is not null
                            )
 FROM  [Item Ledger Entry] ILE1
 where ILE1.[Entry Type] = 4
```

Comment: I have reformatted your SQL to make it more legible. I have no idea how you could tell what it was doing with how it looked previously.

Comment: Thanks Martin, looks much better now